# How to kill duplicates in array without using Set?

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can i delete all duplicates in array without using Set (because it will disturb the order)

And why my loop with splice method doesnt work?

```js
let result = [
  'j', 'a', 'a', 'v',
  'a', 'a', 's', 'c',
  'r', 'i', 'p', 't'
  ]
;


for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        if (result[i] === result[i + 1]){
            result.splice(result.indexOf(result[i]), 1);
        }
}

console.log(result)  //[  "j", "v", "a",  "a",  "s",  "c", "r", "i",  "p",  "t" ]
```

```
expected output - > [  "j", "a",  "v",  "a",  "s",  "c", "r", "i",  "p",  "t" ]
```

Comment: "*without using Set (because it will disturb the order)*" sets preserve the insertion order.

Comment: "because it will disturb the order" It won't, tho

Comment: The text and the expected output are conflicting. Do you actually mean you want to remove all the sequential duplicates instead of all duplicates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method fails in your condition:

```
if (result[i] === result[i + 1])
```

Because you only check to see if the next item is the same as the current item and not against the entire array.

To solve this you can create a new array and push in this array only the values that are not already there, thus eliminating duplicates.

```
const result2 = [];
for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i += 1) {
    if (result2.indexOf(result[i])>-1) {
    continue;
  }
  result2.push(result[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could filter the array and have a look to the predecessor.

```js
const
    data = ['j', 'a', 'a', 'v', 'a', 'a', 's', 'c', 'r', 'i', 'p', 't'],
    result = data.filter((v, i, a) => v !== a[i - 1]);

console.log(...result);
```

Comment: most probably the solution wanted (javascript :) , but technically this duplicates 'a' so not the solution asked

Comment: @malarres, but it returns the wanted pattern.

Comment: @malarres No? At least the result is the same as OP's expected output. I suppose they actually wanted to ask how to remove sequential duplicates.

Comment: OP question: `How can i delete all duplicates in array without using Set (because it will disturb the order)` but yes you're right `expected output - > [  "j", "a",  "v",  "a",  "s",  "c", "r", "i",  "p",  "t" ]`

Answer (score 0):

I think to remove duplicate from an array write a function that do the job and return the array with unique item in it. Please find the below code that serve the propose.

```
function removeDuplicate(data) {
const tempArray = [];
data.forEach( (item) => {
  if (tempArray.indexOf(item) === -1) {
    tempArray.push(item);
  }
});
return tempArray;
```

}

let result = [
'j', 'a', 'a', 'v',
'a', 'a', 's', 'c',
'r', 'i', 'p', 't'
];

result  = removeDuplicate(result );